# distinct values from one to many table relation?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a table 'tbl_user' with columns user_id, uer_name,user_address. And product table 'tbl_product' with columns product_id, product_price, product_date, user_id(This one from tbl_user). So I want to select distinct values from this whole table relation based on product date.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, this should work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT d.*, u.*
FROM tbl_product p
  INNER JOIN tbl_user u ON p.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE product_date = @paramDate
```

Or you may need to clarify your question.